# Map every element to its position in the array as if it was sorted

Tags: java, big-o

I'm currently preping for coding interviews and I want to know what other have for this question.

Map every element to its position in the array as
if it was sorted. Now we need to return a new array where every element is mapped to its
position in the sorted array.

- Input: `[33, 44, 33, 11, 22]`
- Output: `[2, 4, 3, 0, 1]`

`[11, 22, 33, 33, 44]` (how it would look like if it was sorted)

What would be your approach and solution to the time and space complexities?

The farthest I got was:

```java
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> findAllPositions(List<Integer> input) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> sortedInput = new ArrayList<>(input);
    Collections.sort(sortedInput);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedInput.size(); i++) {
        int num = sortedInput.get(i);
        if (!result.containsKey(num)) {
            result.put(num, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        result.get(num).add(i);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(33, 44, 33, 11, 22);
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> positions = findAllPositions(input);
    System.out.println(positions); // {1=[0, 1], 2=[2], 3=[3], 4=[4]}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to "find all positions"? I recommend keeping track of where each element ends up.

Comment: Note that you could simplify your 'multimap' code to remove the if statement with `results.computeIfAbsent(sortedInput.get(i), v-> new ArrayList<>()).add(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a map you could create index, value records and sort those. The results could then be used to generate the result:

```
record Pair(int index, int value) {}

List<Integer> sorted = IntStream.range(0, input.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> new Pair(i, input[i]))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::value))
    .map(Pair::index).toList();
int[] output = IntStream.range(0, input.length)
    .map(sorted::indexOf).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify according to your code

```
  public static List<Integer> findAllPositions(List<Integer> input) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> sortedInput = new ArrayList<>(input);

    Collections.sort(sortedInput);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedInput.size(); i++) {
      int num = sortedInput.get(i);
      if (!result.containsKey(num)) {
        result.put(num, new ArrayList<>());
      }
      result.get(num).add(i);
    }

    List<Integer> result2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); j++) {
      List<Integer> tmp =result.get(input.get(j));
      if (tmp != null && tmp.size() > 0) {
        result2.add(tmp.get(0));
        tmp.remove(0);
      }
    }
    return result2;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(33, 44, 33, 11, 22);
    System.out.println(findAllPositions(input));
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).